# Send a custom email when WooCommerce checkout button is pressed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, email-notifications

I am trying to send a custom email whenever the checkout button is pressed for Woocommerce using PHP.

This email will be sent alongside with the email notifications of wooCommerce.
I have used this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512552/woocommerce-execute-php-per-product-on-successful-checkout#32512745), and edited the code like:

```
//execute some php on successfull checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_32512552_payment_complete' );
function so_32512552_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

        if ( $item['product_id'] > 0 ) {
            $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

            // the message
            $msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

            // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
            $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

            // send email
            mail("info@example.com","My subject",$msg);


        }
    }
}
```

But nothing seems to happen. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because this hook is **fired only when the order status is completed** … 
Also is better to use **`wp_mail()`** than **`mail()`** function.

Instead you could try to use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_thankyou`** action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_email_notification', 10, 1 );
function custom_email_notification( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! $order_id ) return;

    ## THE ORDER DATA ##

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Iterating through each order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $order_item ) {

        // Accessing to the protected data of the WC_Order_Item_Product object
        $order_item_data = $order_item->get_data();

        // Get the associated WC_Product object
        $product = $order_item->get_product();

        // Accessing to the WC_Product object protected data
        $product_data = $product->get_data();
    }


    ## SENDING AN EMAIL (outside the loop is better to send it once) ##

    $to = "test@mail.com";
    $subject = "the subject here";
    $content = "Here goes your message";

    // Sending your custom email notification
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $content );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce 3+ and works.

> The **`woocommerce_thankyou`** hook is triggered in order-received page …

Comment: thanks so much for the very detailed and usefull code. I just tried this replacing test@mail.com with my email address, but i didnt get any email unfortunatelly. The thank you page was reached.

Comment: @xbass540 Hello, this code is tested and completely works … so there is a problem with your hosting outgoing emails related with your Wordpress installation…

Comment: i thought about that but currently the default woocommerce emails are sent without problem. What short of setting should i look for changing in my server settings?

Comment: @xbass540 I don't know … Also you should look in spam email folder…