# Send a custom email with a dynamic subject and recipient in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sms, orders

In Woocommerce, I have been able to create custom meta box with a button, which send an email, using [Send a custom email when WooCommerce checkout button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267781/send-a-custom-email-when-woocommerce-checkout-button-is-pressed/45268434#45268434) existing answer code. It displays the following metabox:

[image: MetaBox]

So when I click the button it sends an email, which works just fine.

**My question:**  
How I can customize that code to send custom email as I need to send "Subject" only (with order id and payment total) to email address, which should be in format:  `mobilenumber@domain.com` (so it will be send to SMS gateway and delivered as SMS on a mobile device)?

**For example:** 
Email address:  123456789@smsgateway.com 
subject:  Your order {order_id} has been done. Total: {order_total}. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

The first function is optional and will display a required checkout field for the mobile phone.

The second function code display a metabox in woocommerce admin order edit pages with a custom button that will trigger the action. When pressed it will send custom email to the SMS gateway with:

- a specific dynamic subject containing the order number and the total amount
- a specific email address made of the customer mobile phone and a specific SMS gateway domain name like `'smsgateway.com'`.

> **Note:** When using `wp_mail()` function, the message is mandatory (if there is no message or an empty one, the email is not sent).

The code:

```
// 1. Add mandatory billing phone field (and save the field value in the order)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_billing_mobile_phone_field', 20, 1 );
function add_billing_mobile_phone_field( $billing_fields ) {
    $billing_fields['billing_mobile_phone'] = array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'label'       => __("Mobile phone", "woocommerce") ,
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'required'    => true,
        'clear'       => true,
    );
    return $billing_fields;
}

// 2. Send a specific custom email to a SMS gateway from a meta box

// Add a metabox
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'order_metabox_email_to_sms' );
function order_metabox_email_to_sms() {
    add_meta_box( 'sms_notification',
    __( 'SMS notification', "woocommerce" ),
    'order_metabox_content_email_to_sms',
    'shop_order', 'side', 'high' );
}

// Metabox content: Button and SMS processing script
function order_metabox_content_email_to_sms(){
    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow != 'post.php' || get_post_type($_GET['post']) != 'shop_order' )
        return; // Exit

    if ( ! ( isset($_GET['post']) && $_GET['post'] > 0 ) )
        return; // Exit

    $order_id = $_GET['post'];

    $is_sent = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_sms_email_sent', true );

    // Sending SMS
    if ( isset($_GET['send_sms']) && $_GET['send_sms'] && ! $is_sent ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // Using the billing mobile phone if it exist, or the billing phone if not.
        if( $mobile_phone = $order->get_meta( '_billing_mobile_phone' ) ) {
            $phone = $mobile_phone;
        } else {
            $phone = $order->get_billing_phone();
        }

        // Email address: Customer mobile phone + @ + sms domain
        $send_to = $phone . '@' . 'smsgateway.com';

        // Subject with the order ID and the order total amount
        $subject = sprintf(
            __("Your order number %d with a total of %s is being processed. Thank you.", "woocommerce"),
            $order_id, html_entity_decode( strip_tags( wc_price( $order->get_total() ) ) )
        );

        // Message: It is required (we just add the order number to it).
        $message = $order_id;

        // Sending this custom email
        $trigger_send = wp_mail( $send_to, $subject, $message );

        // Displaying the result
        if( $trigger_send ) {
            $result  = '<span style="color:green;">' ;
            $result .= __( "The SMS is being processed by the gateway." );

            // On email sent with success, Mark this email as sent in the Order meta data (To avoid repetitions)
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_sms_email_sent', $trigger_send );
        } else {
            $result  = '<span style="color:red;">' ;
            $result .= __( "Sorry, but the SMS is not processed." );
        }
        $result .= '</span>';
    }

    // Displaying the button
    $href = '?post=' . $order_id . '&action=edit&send_sms=1';
    $send_text = isset($is_sent) && $is_sent ? '<em><small style="float:right;"> ('. __("Already sent") . ')</small></em>' : '';
    echo '<p><a href="' . $href . '" class="button">' . __( "Send SMS" ) . '</a>'.$send_text.'</p>';

    // Displaying a feed back on send
    echo isset($result) ? '<p><small>' . $result . '</small></p>' : false;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**The four possibilities within this metabox:**

[image]

> Once the SMS is sent once, the feature becomes inactive, to avoid any repetitions.

Comment: Don't know what happens but i lost my snippet for metabox ...
If i can ask you how to create a button for metabox to execute that action (to send email) ?

This is what i've got right know just for metabox to appear:

Comment: `add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_box_odoslatsms' );
 function add_meta_box_odoslatsms()
 {
    add_meta_box( 'custom_order_meta_box', __( 'Odoslat SMS' ),
        'custom_metabox_content',
  'shop_order', 'side', 'high');
 }
`

Comment: and

`function custom_metabox_content(){
    $post_id = isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : false;
    if(! $post_id ) return; // Exit

    
}`

Comment: Looks good, but in every case i'm getting:  Sorry, but the SMS is not processed.

Is it because i'm creating order manually from back end ?

The thing is i use WooCommerce for order management where i create order from back end only (no fron end interaction).

Thank you

Comment: I'm looking for advice to this "meta update" as i would like to be able to send SMS 2-3 times or to be able to set this value in this snippet.

`// On email sent with success, Mark this email as sent in the Order meta data (To avoid repetitions)
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_sms_email_sent', $trigger_send );
        } else {
            $result  = '<span style="color:red;">' ;
            $result .= __( "Chyba, SMS nemohla byt odoslana." );`